# Taking a daily census using a declarative query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a data set like the following:

```
ID  admission_date  discharge_date
1   2016-02-27      2016-05-06
2   2016-03-06      2016-05-13
3   2016-03-14      2016-05-03
4   2016-04-01      2016-05-19
5   2016-04-03      2016-06-15
6   2016-04-06      2016-05-14
7   2016-04-27      2016-05-03
8   2016-04-27      2016-05-10
9   2016-04-28      2016-05-04
10  2016-04-28      2016-05-01
11  2016-04-28      2016-05-14
12  2016-04-29      2016-05-02
13  2016-04-29      2016-05-01
```

I would like to count up the number of rows occurring in each row (i.e. take a daily census) in a given range. For a daily census ranging from '2016-05-01' to '2016-05-02', the expected result is:

```
date          census
2016-05-01    13
2016-05-02    11 (rows 10 and 13 do not count because patient
                  was not hospitalized on 2016-05-02)
```

I'm struggling to find a way to correctly tally up the census counts for all days. I went down the route of window functions for a while, but I could not figure out a way to exclude rows to achieve the results above. Currently I'm trying to solve this by using cursors.

So the question is: **is it possible to do this using a purely declarative SQL query?**

To show a contrasting viewpoint on what people consider "census", [this thread in Tableau forums](https://community.tableau.com/thread/107815) discusses an almost identical idea, but the major difference is that the method discussed there assumes that, for 2016-05-01, you will not count patients who were discharged on 2016-05-01 (this idea is what enables you to sum up each day using window functions), for example. This would decrease the total above for 2016-05-01 to 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if you have a dates table. If not, you can generate them with a recursive cte and use it for the query.

```
--Use the recursive cte only if there isn't a dates table in the database   
--Generates all dates in 2016
with dates(dt) as (select cast('2016-01-01' as date) 
                   union all
                   select dateadd(day,1,dt) 
                   from dates
                   where dt<'2017-01-01'
                  )
--Actual query
select d.dt,count(distinct t.id)
from tbl t
join dates d on d.dt>=t.admission_date and d.dt<=t.dishcarge_date
where d.dt>='2016-05-01' and d.dt<='2016-05-02' --change this as needed
group by d.dt
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that only provides the census on the dates you have listed:

```
with d as (
      select v.*
      from t cross apply
           (values (admission_date, 1, 0),
                   (discharge_date, 0, 1)
           ) v(dte, incoming, outgoing)
     )
select dte,
       (sum(sum(incoming)) over (order by dte) - sum(sum(outgoing)) over (order by dte)
       ) as census
from d
group by dte
order by dte;
```

This is likely to be the fastest method.  This can be extended to all dates if you have a calendar table or want to use a recursive CTE.

Comment: This actually addresses the scenario I described in the last paragraph of the question, but I actually have a use case for this as well and this is MUCH shorter than what I'm currently using, so thanks for this! edit: I have to say that I need to stare at that to parse it, but I can see from running the query that it indeed gets me the right data!